# Should C++ allocator::allocate throw or not?

Tags: c++, std, allocator

The [Allocator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) and [std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate) doesn't say whether `allocate` will throw or not.

So when I'm writing a container using allocators, how to know whether to check return type or use `catch`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table in the **Requirements** section of the page you reference gives quite enough information when it may throw exceptions and when it must not throw exceptions. Below is a quote when an allocator may throw exceptions.

> `a.allocate(n)` allocates storage suitable for n objects of type `T`, but does not construct them. May throw exceptions.

What type of exceptions is thrown is not described there and maybe is implementation dependent. Generally it is `std::bad_alloc` in STL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it may throw. And the exception is `std::bad_alloc` since it use the `allocator` passed to it while `std::allocator` will throw `std::bad_alloc`.

In the page you refered introduces two scenarios:

> 1. Calls a.allocate(n)
> 2. Additionally passes memory locality hint hint. Calls a.allocate(n, hint) if possible. If not possible (e.g. a has no two-argument member function allocate()), calls a.allocate(n)

so basically you can turn to this:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate